# Why B+ trees should not have left biasing as well as right biasing for the same tree?

Tags: b-tree

Learning the fundamentals of B trees. I understand that they are either left biased or right biased to facilitate the ordering of child nodes.

According to me, if both biasing exist in the same tree, that may lead to ambiguity regarding the location of child node. Also, this may increase the total time required to fetch the data.

Is this assumption correct? I remember my teacher asking this question in class when he was describing b trees. However, now I cannot pinpoint exactly what was the reason for the question. 
Please advise.

Comment: How can you have 2 opposing biases?  Doesn't that subvert the whole meaning of "bias"?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how b trees are constructed on a computer and how biasing is actually done. Maybe I'll know when I read more.